# JSON LD recognized by Google, but not Facebook pixel ( Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-ld, structured-data, facebook-pixel

I have implemented a Json-ld dynamic creation process to boost my SEO. The JSON is created through the use of Jbuilder ( code is in a partial), rendered in a script tag with a type of "application/ld+json". All of it is wrapped up  in a content_for, so that I can reuse the logic.

Once it has been implemented, I started to get this error in my console: "[Facebook Pixel] - Unable to parse JSON-LD tag. Malformed JSON found: ' "

- I tested my Json-LD on the [google structured data tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) and everything came back ok.
- I've added an hand written JSON-LD in my script tag, instead of my aforementioned logic,
  everything looked ok. No error was displayed in the console, and [Chrome Facebook Pixel
  Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-pixel-helper/fdgfkebogiimcoedlicjlajpkdmockpc) was able to find my JSON-LD.

Bottom line, it appears that using my dynamic logic with the partials create a random " ' ", which makes no sense for me.

Any of you ever had the same issue, or something similar ?

Answer (score 0):

May be templating engine is messing you up. You might consider using the json-ld gem to validate the output as part of continuous integration (you can also semantically validate the content using other gems).

I’ve had success using JSON-LD in Haml, but I just use to_json from a Hash hierarchy which has always worked well for me.